# add custom buttons to select popup in jquery mobile

Tags: select, popup, jquery-mobile

I am using the jquery Mobile  with multiple select option and data-native-menu as false. The default behavior is that the user can select multiple options and on clicking anywhere else on the screen, the values are set. I want to change this.
I want to add a button at the bottom of the select popup. Only on click of this button, the values selected should be applied. Any ideas as to how I can achieve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It can't be. What you want is changing the UI of mobile devices. That's hardly possible to do for native apps, web apps have no access to these things at all.

What you could try:

1. If your app is targeted for specific devices, you can measure the height of the selection-popup.
2. Create a toolbar that fits exactly above the popup. Add a button to it (eg. 'Done').
3. Add a listener so you get notified when the user presses the 'Done'-button =)!

Comment: Thanks Tim. I will try adding a toolbar and see.